# When are "blatantly off-topic" flags marked helpful?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic, helpful-flags

From [this FAQ](/a/105395),

> Flags to close a question **will be dismissed as helpful as soon as another user votes to close it**. However, if you don't have enough reputation to see close votes, it will appear as if nothing has happened until more users vote to close and the question is actually closed.

From *Glorfindel*'s comment (deleted, merged into [this post](/a/299001))

> ... others **voting to close it with *the same reason* as your flag**, or the question is finally closed, it will be considered as helpful

Assuming the latter is up-to-date, if I raise a flag for a reason of **Blatantly Off-topic**, since 3Kers do not have that option (but a custom OT reason), then **is my flag still able to be dismissed as helpful because of a close vote of the same reason?** (I know it'll be helpful if the Q's finally closed.)

Comment: Technically, "off topic" is the reason, I think... but I don't have any proof. So if the question is blatantly off topic, hopefully the person in the close queue will vote to close it as off topic with a custom reason.

Comment: @iBug that was a quick test. Alex' answer is right, I was slightly misinformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised [the same question](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3990773#3990773) in chat, and [Shog9 answered](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3990777#3990777):

> flags are marked helpful on the first matching close-vote type - however, I'm pretty sure that doesn't match subtype.
>   So any OT vote would mark helpful all OT flags

Comment: So do you mean I can **flag** for any OT reason?

Comment: @iBug Probably? The review queue doesn't

Comment: @iBug You can flag anything for any reason. But if the reason you picked doesn't seem right to reviewers, there's a good chance of them clicking Leave Open instead of looking for another reason that applies.