# General off-topic flag?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Why isn't there just a generic off-topic flag?  This question really should be flagged as such, but it would be too bothersome to flag with a custom reason: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3159239

Comment: Close/Flag >  Off topic because > Other > type "clothes" or "shopping". Easy enough. This is an edge case, not something you'll have to do every day and not worth the downsides of a generic OT flag (such as people having no clue why their question was closed).

Comment: @WesleyMurch: people without close privileges don't have the `other` option under off-topic.

Comment: @Quantas: I see, you have to select "Custom" and type out the whole message or something? Still the second part of my comment is applicable.

Comment: I would also add that these extreme cases usually get closed immediately and don't *really* need to be flagged (although it is still appropriate to do so). For anyone who can't see it, the question was *"I want to buy through online so need a trusted one. Moreover, right product at right time at my resident is a must. Is there such a site for men's clothing?"*.

Comment: @WesleyMurch They don't usually get closed immediately. but the current consensus seem to be that those who can only flag should not try to handle those generic off topic questions.

Comment: @WesleyMurch See for instance [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192768/213634) where the mod specifically rejects a generic off-topic question for the reason that it side-steps the process.

Comment: @dcaswell - "on-hold" means "closed". It's not a status tag. Those are red.

Comment: @dcaswell - I repeat, the "on-hold" tag is NOT a status tag. It refers to questions on SO being closed. The text below is automatic and in this case is misleading but this question is still a duplicate.

Comment: @chrisF Thanks for your patience. I feel like an absolute dunce for not understanding this earlier.

Answer (score 7):

Because then people would just use that instead of anything else, instead of providing a meaningful close message.  You should have taken the time to use a custom close reason.

Comment: It can take ages to remove horribe posts like those with custom flags - this really shouldn't be something that needs a custom flag.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Such questions do not make up a significant portion of closed posts.  If you don't have 20 seconds to type out a custom reason then there are still several tends of thousands of posts that can use an existing close reason for you to spend your votes on.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy why does a custom flag make it slower than a generic off-topic flag would?  They all go to the same queue and all appear to anyone looking at off-topic posts would see it.

Comment: Is there even a way to submit a custom flag without sending it right to a moderator?  Serious question.

Comment: @Jamal No, but there's no reason for a custom flag, just use a custom close reason.

Comment: I mean for those without close vote privileges.  In such cases, I just decline from flagging unless the post specifically needs moderator attention.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Because for a user with the privileges of the OP the only place than can enter a custom close reason is when they flag for Diamond Moderator Attention. That's a different queue. There are three obvious choices 1) Flagging for Diamond Moderator attention. 2) Using an Off-Topic flag that's not accurate 3) Not flagging at all. As you can see by the comment above mine many people choose not to flag.