# How should I flag questions that are totally unrelated to programming?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

Sometimes, I find a post that is totally unrelated to programming. It's either asking about why can't they connect with their service, why can't they login to Facebook and such. My question is, as stated in the title, how should I flag it?

If I flag it as `off-topic`, which of the options should I choose? It's not asking for code, nor asking to fix a code, nor about servers, and it doesn't belong to any of the sites listed.

I know we can just flag it as `other` and describe what it's about, but since it's wasting moderator's time, is there a better option?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." - It is the first off-topic option.

Comment: Well, it's not about computing hardware and software either..

Comment: What is it about then? You are being overly hypothetical now.

Comment: @Oded For example "How to kill these slugs on my roses"

Comment: And Facebook is a piece of software, as are most services on the web.

Comment: Use of software is still software. The first option is the one you want for the situation you describe.

Comment: Now that's my question, what is the question about?

Comment: Not being able to log in to Facebook is 'general computing hardware and software'.

Comment: You are overthinking it. If something is obviously off-topic, it is obviously so. If none of the canned answers apply, use the "other" and supply your own off-topic reason.

Comment: @RichardTingle - Off-topic -> Other -> "... it is about slugs and not programming".

Comment: Perhaps i am :) But thanks for clearing the info, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Oded - Is there any reason why there isn't a canned reason for completely off topic and we have to supply a custom message for these cases?

Comment: @Oded While that is true it has always seemed to me like a waste of moderator time, any 3K+ user could close such a flagged question but a moderator has to be called in to do so

Comment: Agree with martin, this might be a feature request.

Comment: @RichardTingle - huh? 5 users can close such a question. No moderator required. off-topic -> other doesn't require moderators. (wasn't talking about flag -> Other (requires moderator attention))

Comment: @Oded As a 3K+ user I can vote to close as Off topic-->"other" but back when I was sub 3K Off topic-->"other" wasn't available as a flag, only "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)"

Comment: @MartinSmith - not disagreeing with you. The top level reason ("This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.") is what you  are talking about - as it stands, on [so] clicking it would require an additional click on a different option.

Comment: @RichardTingle - Yeah - fair enough. Didn't get you first time.

Comment: Also, take a look at [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202963/213634) to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202945/213634

Comment: @Oded The problem with the first option is that it ends "You may find help on SuperUser." For those blatantly OT questions, one shouldn't really direct the OP to SuperUser (or any other SE-site, actually).

Comment: `it's wasting moderator's time`.. moderators are meant to do that right? :P

Comment: @Mr_Green well not quite, they are not supposed to do things community can do, too. But one can flag with first close reason and expect 3k users to write better fitting one in the close queue, if needed.