# How do I flag a question that should be closed for none of the provided reasons?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, vote-to-close

So I just came across this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908316/ruminations-on-technology-trust

And wanted to close it on the grounds that it has absolutely nothing to do with programming. So I click `flag->It should be closed for another reason` on the basis that the subheading to that options describes the reason:

> This question does not meet this site's standards and should be closed.

So then I click `off-topic because...` underneath which it says

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined in the help center.

Yup. Perfect. Then I get a list of options, *none of which* describes the problems with that post:

1. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. **Nope, the question isn't about general hardware and software**
2. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. **Nope, not about that**
3. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. **Nope**
4. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. **No, unrelated**
5. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. **No...**
6. This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. **Errr... Maybe but do they really want it???**

So what am I supposed to do, just send it off to someone on some other Stack Exchange site? Why would this list not be exhaustive?

Comment: And pretty much also a duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186262/213634) (and a gazillion others) as well, even though my question never got an answer.