# "Nevermind, I forgot to include X library in my code"

Tags: discussion, too-localized

#### This is RE: [Closing changes: [on hold], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154)

On SO, I see questions a lot that are resolved because of a trivial proplem, such as forgetting to link jQuery, or a missing semi-colon.  Before, I voted to close those as too-localized, which is how I understood it should be used.

### The Issue

With the close reasons changing, I'm unsure how to vote these for close, and deletion.  They provideo no use to future visitors.  The primary reason is, a question such as "Click handler not firing when I press X" is unlikely to be the same problem another user whom forgot jQuery on their page is experiencing.

### Examples

[Why when i change attribute class with JS nothing happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517837/why-when-i-change-attribute-class-with-js-nothing-happen)

- Resolved because a style sheet was a .LESS file

[get class of parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17109593/1074592)

- The question was actually resolved by making a test case.  I.e., at the time of asking
  the code was already correct.

### Resolution?

I believe these questions should be **immediately deleted**, if there is a comment indicating a **resolution unrelated** to the question **title** and **body**.

How should I handle these questions when I come upon them?

- flag for moderator review pointing to the comment?
- Allow them to exist and encourage a answer to be provided and accepted?
- Ask the OP to delete their question?
- Close for **_____________** reason
- Edit the question to mimic the solution
- Other?

Comment: `XXX is undeclared` <-- "OOhhh, I'm having the same problem!" - Search on Google, come to SO. "AH!!! I need to include a library!". End Result: A happy camper... Basically I'm saying that not all of such questions are too localized.

Comment: I think this is a dupe, but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: Related: [How to flag a typo question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186366/102937).

Comment: @Mysticial this won't work if the error message pointing to that library is missing

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks.  That question points to flagging as `To Localized`, which is no longer an option.  Have a recomendation, going forward?  I also added two recent examples, to the post, and proposed rephrasing the question to be found on search engines easier, re, @mystical.

Comment: That's not a "Too Localized" flag; it is a custom flag with a typed-in description.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I misread the post.  Well, thanks.  I got my answer :-)  Should I delete this question, as it's a duplicate?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand [No](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates) :-)

Comment: *"Whom are you?" he asked, for he had been to night school.*