# What is better to do with question that at first sign was great, but after author's remark looks like a 'local incident'?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, up-votes

What is better to do with question like this: [Images not showing on Jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18466188/876298)?

Firstly it was looking as an interesting (valuable) question.

But lately, the question's author add the remark (add the answer) that he made just a typo.

This question has several upvotes that makes it attractive (plus the promising title) for future readers. IMHO, the value of the reading this post will be not high.

***UPDATED***

Ok, now this question is closed. It has the ***[on hold]*** state (we can see it in the title).

Does it help the *SO* user (especially newbie) to save his\her time when the user will search solution in similar cases? - I think, *NO*.
 
*Why?* - Because this question still has the high rating (+3) and it still has valuable title, because the user don't know why it is in ***[on hold]*** state. I think that the user will open this question.

What does the ***[on hold]*** state mean for the new *SO* user?

The **too localized** resolution is deprecated now. IMHO, it was more clearly than ***on hold*** in such cases.

***#2. UPDATED***

Typo was just a sample, it is only one reason for the question's "devaluation". The another reason - the author add the remark that the issue takes place only on *X88 architecture in the first Monday of July*, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate (or very closely related): [Which close reason should I use to close “typo” questions now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192846/which-close-reason-should-i-use-to-close-typo-questions-now) See also [Close all the typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Comment: Close or delete, those are your two options. Without moderator intervention, closure must precede deletion. So pick an appropriate reason and get on with your day.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typo question, so it should be closed ([discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)). I've voted for closure as "off-topic".

Comment: Ok, now this question in closed - has ***[on hold]*** state. Does it help me (the SO user) to save my time (please read my comment to answer by Andre Silva) when I will search solution in similar cases? It still has high rating (+3) and it still has valuable title, because I don't know why it is now in ***[on hold]*** state. What does ***[on hold]*** state mean for the new user on *SO*?

Comment: @AlexK It is on hold because we (5 users with 3000+ rep) voted to close. As to how valuable it is -- well, it depends on your opinion, but for me, it's downright useless. A typo is the classic "too localized" type of problem.

Comment: I (new *SO* user) don't know that this question is too localized. I need to open it and read comments

Comment: @AlexK you *can* read the comments on closed questions.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it does not save my time. I mean that clear resolution in title, for example ***[too localized]*** or ***[typo]*** is better for understanding than the ***[on hold]***.

Comment: @AlexK Then you should post a `feature-request` kind of question here, asking for clearer on-hold title tags.

Comment: Probably you are right. But what about manual edition the title?

Comment: @AlexK Well, what about it?

Comment: Is it a good practice to change the title in this case? [on hold] -> [typo]

Comment: @AlexK No, not manually. And you can't change that tag anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your concern is that it’s not immediately obvious from the search results that this question won’t be useful to you, so you’ll waste time reading it. A valid concern! That’s *why* the question has been closed.

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mis-spelled file name, rather than programming. – Servy yesterday
>
> That's fine. It's not meant to be insulting or to punish you in any way. It's simply a way of saying that this question won't be useful to future readers, and closing that will help indicate to them that this is unlikely to help solve their problems. – Servy 1 hour ago

Closed questions (and "on hold" is *the same as closed*, it just shows differently for the
first few days) are left out of search results most of the time.

Comment: `Closed questions are left out of search results most of the time` - I've just find (with help of *SO* search engine) the question closed on October

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure exactly what the algorithm is. I think they're pushed down the priority list. And often they're eventually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this as a problem. Probably the answer will not be upvoted, but the question can be of concerning to others in the future making the same mistake.

Besides, (IMO) the O.P. was coherent posting an answer to his own question explaining the problem, instead of leaving the question being upvoted and letting readers in the blindness.

Comment: If I faced a problem with using image with this framework I will start with search on SO. Right? And I will start with questions with high reputation. Right? And in this case it seems to me that this case is not valuable

Comment: Yes, I agree with your workflow process. But, the answer is there (users would also look to answers, since the question interests), so one would just move on to the next on the list. It is just one opinion, but there be other better than mine (+1 for asking).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was trying to give myself the answer in the same way as you give :)