# What existing close reason should I use for a question that is "Too Localized"?

Tags: discussion

I want to vote to close this question: [Unable to deseralize JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19001392/838807)

The reason is because that after seeing the solution to the problem I cannot see any reason why this would be of any help to anyone in the future, including the OP of the question.

I can see that the problem demonstrates the need to ensure you name your properties correctly, but I still feel this is nothing more than a typo on the part of the OP.

So assuming that this question should be closed: What is the new close vote reason to use when a question is too localized?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186376/201151

Comment: @bummi: I see, good to know... however, based on the fact that the question has since received no close votes, and actually won an upvote, I am unsure if I should be voting to close it

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that this question is too localized. Here's why:

1. The questioner didn't know a specific piece of information about JSON Serialization and described his problem in a general way that is searchable.
2. This piece of information is not immediately knowable, that is, the information has to be discovered.
3. The answer given not only describes what the user got wrong, but explains it generally enough that anyone who searches for this problem will see his answer.

These three factors mean that while the user made a seemingly trivial mistake, there's a good chance that his problem will help others.

A 'typo' question would be when a user made an inadvertent typographical error that caused the problem.  This was not inadvertent -- the user meant to name his method that, he just didn't have some deeper knowledge that he needed.