# What happened to the "other" option for off-topic flagging?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, off-topic

Don't get me wrong, I like the new flagging system (except the *wording* of the close reasons), but something is wrong I believe.

When you want to flag a question as [what apparently ***used*** to mean] off topic, you are presented with a dialog with common options and messages. Ok. That's different. After studying it a bit, I figured out that the dialog also covers common close reasons a bit. Ok, I guess? I finally found the way to flag a question for migration, but I was surprised to find that there was *no* "other" option!

The question in question (hehe) was "[Unix: Trying to increment a calender year and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386877/unix-trying-to-increment-a-calender-year-and-display)". For one thing, the question sounds homework ("[sic] I have a unix assignment"). Another being that we have a [site *dedicated* to Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A better duplicate is [No custom off topic message when flagging on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so)