# Comment inbox notifications show post, but not comment

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, global-inbox

When someone leaves a comment on an answer I've posted, clicking the inbox notification loads and highlights the correct answer but does not ensure that the *comment* which generated the notification is highlighted or even visible.

This is mildly annoying for comments on answers longer than 1 screen, and considerably more frustrating when multiple long answers *and* lengthy comment threads exist as I must then carefully scroll to the bottom of the current answer, expand the comments, and then scroll to the bottom of *that* list - with the constant risk of over-scrolling to the wrong answer.

#### Expected behavior

Following a link to a comment, ([for instance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so/185873?noredirect=1#comment769600_185873)) should scroll to and highlight the comment being linked to, expanding all comments below a given post *if necessary*.

Comment: Does this happen on posts that do not contain pictures?  In general, we do try to get you to the right spot but sometimes those damn images ruin everything.

Comment: yeah, the only time it works would be accidentally on very short answers with only one or two comments @Brian.

Answer (score 3):

Marking this as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) to force myself to work on it soon. I've spent some time trying to do this in the past but it's a huge rabbit hole since our actual post contents are `WebView`s and the rest of the views are not, so it requires a lot of complexity to figure out "Hey is the page done rendering yet?" which you need to know before you know how much to scroll down to show comments.