# "on hold" when should have been migrated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, on-hold

[Run external program instead of builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443108/run-external-program-instead-of-builtin)

It appears all 5 voters suggested Super User, yet the question was not migrated, but put "on hold".

What gives?

Comment: This seems like another good argument for the suggestion: ["Remove mentions of other sites in Stack Overflow off topic reasons"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186802/remove-mentions-of-other-sites-in-stack-overflow-off-topic-reasons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The votes it received are not votes to migrate. They are simple off-topic votes. The dialog is the following:

> [image]

The users have chosen the first option, which simply puts the question on hold and includes the message you noticed.

The option at the bottom leads to the migration dialog. That would have lead to actual migration should all users have chosen to migrate the question to Super User.

Comment: So 5 people voted for Super User, and instead of migrating it gets closed... and that makes sense how?!

Comment: No @steven, 5 people voted to close it as off-topic for the reasons stated. SU might be a suggestion to look into, but the users might not necessarily have been fully confident it would be a good fit there either.

Comment: You could flag it for mod attention and ask for migration. I don't know SU well enough to say it would be accepted.

Comment: It's also possible that people intend to migrate it, but don't know that the first option is not for migration.

Comment: @doubleDown Yes, maybe they meant to migrate. Perhaps the heading off topic is [not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024/194906) the [best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185271/194906) label to [describe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185109/194906) that set of [reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186635/194906).

Comment: This just happened to me, and I assumed my close reason was a request to migrate.  At the least, it should be up to the user (and entirely consistent with the on-hold reason) to choose to self-migrate at this point.

Comment: A user can always request migration @NicholasRiley.

Comment: Thanks — this is not clear from the explanation you get on the site that the asker can choose to do anything other than reword his/her question.  I still think the way this action is worded is incredibly confusing.

Comment: Keep in mind though that this might be rejected @NicholasRiley. If a mod request migration to a site, it might well be rejected by the target site if it's not a good fit. So no guarantees.

Comment: Sure, or marked as a dup, whatever; at least the question would make some progress and its asker wouldn't feel abandoned.