# Please allow us to use the top level "off topic" close reason when voting

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I would like to be able to close a question using this top level close reason:

> This question does not appear to be about programming, [within the scope defined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

This text appears when you first open the close vote dialog and are selecting the primary reason you've decided to VTC.

The use case for this close reason should be obvious to all—a question which is totally unrelated to programming and doesn't have a place on any other existing Stack Exchange site. The most prominent examples from my experience are the [Facebook customer support questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076922/problema-with-facebook-thumbinal-on-events-page), but I'm sure that users have come across many other examples of posts asking for help with some application or service thinking that Stack Overflow operates as the customer support center for whatever they are trying to do.

I am fully aware that it is possible to enter a custom message for the close reason but I feel that having this option baked into the close dialog would improve the workflow enormously.

Comment: While we're at it, can *"This question is off-topic because it is about nonsense."* be added to the list of close reasons on Meta?

Comment: IMHO the Facebook questions are the *easiest* to write the custom close reason (*"...off topic because it is about using Facebook."*).

Comment: @juh - agreed - but when you find yourself typing out (or copy pasting) the same reason over and over and over and over and over again, it might be a sign that this reason should be included from the get-go.

Comment: But yes, I agree it'd be nice to have "because it's not about programming" because sometimes the OP starts arguing about the close reason wording ("I'm not asking about kerflooing the blarb, I've already done that and I want to know if I should also floobarg it.") Might go against the idea of custom off-topic reasons though.

Comment: This could also be useful for syntax error questions. Or is there a consensus about which reason to choose for that?

Comment: @Felix I don't think *this* would be the reason you'd use to close syntax error questions. They are *clearly* about programming. The message would just confuse people. Not sure what the consensus is on closing syntax/typo questions, though, since they took away "too localized".

Comment: @Cody: True. I read through [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185102/142802), but it doesn't give me an answer either. I really want something for syntax errors `:(` (unless such questions are accepted now, in which case: what the hell?).

Comment: @Cody Gray: the last thing I remember about typo questions is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/how-to-flag-a-typo-question/186376#186376 - seems strange to me to bother mods about it though. (I used it once [on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392137/error-no-matching-function-or-call-to-my-windows-destructor), the custom close from Andrew Barber looks fine.)

Comment: @Felix [Now that too localized is gone should we embrace the "typo questions"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186181) Sounds like the mods just want us to flag them for immediate deletion. That sort of seems to break the general rule of don't involve mods when the community can handle it, though.

Comment: @Cody: Thanks for that! According to George, if it's a simply type we should close them as "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Comment: @Felix His logic for that is cute and all, but it seems like a stupid idea. That close reason doesn't fit. If we're just supposed to pick something semi-randomly that half-ass fits, why did we go through all the trouble of breaking up "not a real question" into all these separate reasons? I thought about asking a question about this very topic a couple of days ago, but figured it'd just get closed as a dupe of that one.

Comment: You need 3k rep to see the "Other" option? That answers my [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns#comment595454_185102) then.

Comment: This has been asked a lot with many minor variations lately. I think http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so is the canonical request, at least this one has been [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so/185873#185873).

Comment: @gil - I'm sorry, but I fail to see how that post is related. I'm not talking about flagging at all. You link talks about a different issue completely. The flagging issue was only referenced in the comments here.

Comment: About once a day someone requests that the generic off-topic close/flag reason is reinstated. How is your request different?

Comment: My post is a request for an additional close reason. The links you provided talk about users with less than 3K being unable to flag with a custom reason.

Comment: @gil - there very well might be a post out there which requests the same thing - but the one you linked to does not.

Comment: @cod - I removed your addition regarding flagging for users with <3K as to not confuse my request with some [existing requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so).

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. I don't think one little paragraph at the end would make the entire rest of the question irrelevant when it comes to choosing duplicates. It was more like a "special bonus" of implementing this. Unfortunately, this might be a dupe after all: [Closing as "off topic" has just gotten painful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184360)

Comment: @cod - [indeed.](http://www.rankopedia.com/CandidatePix/2374.gif). That post definitely looks like it covers my request... No `feature-request` tag on it though. ;)